# i.m trying to split string by whitespace using c++, where the data from database

Tags: c++, string, c++11, split

*i have tried this, the compilation's result is no error, but the result of running is not suitable*

therefore i'm freaking desperate to solve this problem, i have been trying since 2 weeks ago but got nothing

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int j, count = 0;
    char del[] = ".,/;:";
    string hadis;
    MYSQL* conn;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES* res;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "192.168.43.205", "ibrahim", "hadis", "hadis", 0, NULL, 0);
    if(conn)
    {
        int qstate = mysql_query(conn, "SELECT Isi_Indonesia FROM malik");
        if(!qstate)
        {
            res = mysql_store_result(conn);
            while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
            {
                hadis = row[0];
                for(unsigned int i=0;i<strlen(del);++i)
                {
                    hadis.erase (remove(hadis.begin(), hadis.end(), del[i]), hadis.end());
                    }
                for (j=0; hadis[j]; j++)
                {
                    if (hadis[j] == ' ')
                    count++;
                    cout<< "-";
                }
                cout<<hadis[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know that when you read input from `std::cin` using the `>>` operator, it reads space-delimited values? This operation is true for *any* stream using the `>>` operator. So you can put a string into an [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and read from that using `>>` to get space-delimited values.

Comment: thank you, i'll try to solve it

Comment: please include input, output and desired output in the question

Comment: ps: does it matter that the string is coming from a database? If the question is about the splitting the string part then a [mcve] needs no database

Comment: thank you for all of your comments, i'm newbie programmer, i'll try and fix it